# iOS memory leak according to instruments

Tags: ios, memory-management, instruments

[image: Screen shot of memory leak in instruments]

Please help! I've read the memory management rules, but maybe I'm missing them point somewhere. Instruments is telling me I've got leaks on the following code:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"text", @"score", @"subCount", nil];
NSArray *objects 
    = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sPlateToAdd, [
         [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1] autorelease], 
         [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1] autorelease], 
         nil];

NSMutableDictionary *dPlateToAdd 
    = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];  // 93.4%        
[self.aFinals addObject:dPlateToAdd];    // 6.6%
```

the Keys and Objects arrays aren't being alloc'ed or init'ed, so I dont think I need to release those?

Then the numbers inside Objects are being auto released, so they're ok aren't they?
And sPlateToAdd is a string that gets passed into the method this code is in, so I'm not the owner of that, so I don't need to release it. Or am I?

I've got to be doing something wrong somewhere.

The app runs completely fine in the iPad, but is dog slow on an iPhone 3GS, I'm hoping fixing this memory leak might speed it up a little...

This is the method that creates self.aFinals, which is passed a string from a text input. I've ommitted some of the lines but self.aFinals doesn't interact with them

```
-(id)initWithTerm:(NSString *)thisTerm {
    ...
    ...
    self.aFinals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    return self;
}
```

Then I have about 5 nested loops, that call addPlateToFinals 3 times in the middle of all the loops, creating **thisPlate**, which becomes **sPlateToAdd**

```
// replace 1st occurance
NSString *thisPlate = [thisBase
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:[NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"(^[^%@]+)%@(.*$)", 
        thisChar, 
        thisChar] 
     withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$1%@$2", thisSub]
     ];

     [self addPlateToFinals:thisPlate withSubCount:thisSubCount];
 // replace 2nd occurance
 thisPlate = [thisBase
     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:[NSString stringWithFormat:
         @"(^[^%@]+%@.*)%@",    
         thisChar, 
         thisChar, 
         thisChar] 
     withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$1", thisSub]
     ];

 // then it does it again, with slightly different regex
```

This is the complete method that the leak is coming from:

```
-(void)addPlateToFinals:(NSString *)sPlateToAdd withSubCount:(NSNumber *)nSubCount {
// plate must be less than 7 characters and great than 2 chars
if (
    [sPlateToAdd length] <= [self.nPlateMax intValue] &&
    [sPlateToAdd length] >= [self.nPlateMin intValue]
    ) {    

    NSMutableArray *aSearchFinals = [self arrayOfFinals];

    // add plate if it is not already in the finals array   
    if(![aSearchFinals containsObject:sPlateToAdd]) {

        // filter out results that cannot be converted to valid plates
        NSPredicate *potential = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF MATCHES '^[a-z]{0,3}[0-9]{1,3}[a-z]{0,3}$'"];
        NSPredicate *impossible1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF MATCHES '^[a-z]{2}[0-9]{2,3}[a-z]{2}$'"];
        NSPredicate *impossible2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF MATCHES '^[a-z][0-9]{3}$'"];
        NSPredicate *impossible3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF MATCHES '^[a-z]{2}[0-9]{2}$'"];
        NSPredicate *impossible4 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF MATCHES '^[0-9]{2}[a-z]{2}$'"];

        if(
            [potential evaluateWithObject: sPlateToAdd] && 
            ![impossible1 evaluateWithObject: sPlateToAdd] &&
            ![impossible2 evaluateWithObject: sPlateToAdd] &&
            ![impossible3 evaluateWithObject: sPlateToAdd] &&
            ![impossible4 evaluateWithObject: sPlateToAdd]
        ){                  

            NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"text", @"score", @"subCount", nil];
            NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                    sPlateToAdd, 
                                    [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1] autorelease], 
                                    [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1] autorelease], 
                                    nil
                                ];

            NSDictionary *dPlateToAdd = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];          
            [self.aFinals addObject:dPlateToAdd];   
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What kind of object is leaking?

Comment: Probably, skeater means allocations

Comment: aFinals is a `@property (retain) NSMutableArray *aFinals`?

Comment: Are you are executing on a background thread? If so, it is your responsibility to instantiate and drain your own autorelease pool.

Comment: autorelase pool for two arrays, and dictonary?! Any arguments for this?

Comment: @mja yes aFinals is a property: `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *aFinals;`

Comment: @Justin I'm running a method that I've called from inside a `block` inside `dispatch_async` (I think). Sorry I'm new to all this. This is so I can update a progress bar while my method is running. But I have no idea what you mean about the autorelease pool... so I'll google that

Comment: you don't need an autorelease pool for blocks. memory is managed.

Comment: Because you retain your property, you need to release array passed to self.aFinals like @mja suggested : self.aFinals = [NSMutableArray array];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should show the entire `addPlateToFinals' method, sPlateToAdd could be leaking.

Based on the new added code `self.aFinals` is leaking if the property is declared with retain(and I'm %99 it is). Should be:

`self.aFinals = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]`

or even better:

`self.aFinals = [NSMutableArray array]`

Comment: Ok but don't hate me if my code is awful... I'm converting from web development. I'll attach it to the question.

Comment: Well your reputation is higher than mine! I've added the method

Comment: yeah well now....you have to show me how you call the method :)) i'm especially interested how you create the object that you pass as `sPlateToAdd`

Comment: Ok, I've added the calls to the method, it happens 3 times deep in the center of about 5 nested for loops. I've also showed the line from the init function where I declare/initialize the `self.aFinals` property

Comment: Thanks Valentin, I knew I was releasing self.aFinals, I just didn't see the need to release what I was assigning it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use NSDictonary instead of NSMutableDictonary if it is possible, because *mutable versions of the objects take more memory than immutable*. Also, I have done some cosmetic enhancements to the code

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"text", @"score", @"subCount", nil];
NSArray *objects  = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sPlateToAdd,
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], 
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], 
                    nil];

NSDictonary *dPlateToAdd = [NSDictonary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];  // 93.4%        
[self.aFinals addObject:dPlateToAdd];    // 6.6%
```

Comment: Will that get rid of the memory leak though? And is `NSNumber numberWithInt:1` an exact equivalent of what I've written then? Thanks for your fast reply

Comment: There is no memory leaks in the code you provided. Probably, we speak about allocations or time profiling?

Comment: NSNumber numberWithInt:1 - you are right, it is just more readable

Comment: I've attached a screen shot showing the leaks screen from instruments

Comment: Please, try to replace NSMutableDictonary with NSDictonary and run the tools - wanna see if the allocations will be less.

Comment: Also, please provide the code where you allocate **self.aFinals**

Comment: I replaced the NSMutableDictionary, there seems to be less memory leaked but there are still leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a memory leak of this object without this code being responsible at all.

A memory leak in the Cocoa/Cocoa Touch environment happens when an object is retained more than it's released. The tools will point out where it was allocated, not where it was leaked, because the tools have no way to determine which retain is missing a release. They're just retains and releases; nothing really ties them together but conventions.

First, do a Build & Analyze. This might point out where your code is doing something improper causing a leak. Treat Analyzer warnings seriously, especially if they're related to memory management.

If Build & Analyze doesn't fix your problem, profile through your app again and study the history of the leaked block. This will show you each time the block was retained or released. Look for retains without a corresponding release or autorelease. (You may actually find it easier to simply read through your code, looking for unbalanced retains, without Instruments.)

Comment: thanks, the Analyzer doesn't give me any warnings about my code, it just mentions some deprecated code in third party plug ins I'm using. Am I retaining a variable when I pass it into a method?

Comment: Not unless that method explicitly retains it. But if that method passes it to something else, which passes it to something else, which happens to retain it and not release it later… memory leak. It can really be quite a hunt. That's why block history is so useful.